# How do I create a unique indicator in SQL based on subset of columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I have a list of people that could have more than 1 row in Oracle (SQL). Such as below:

| NAME | SSN | ADDRESS | COUNTY | PHONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 123 MAIN ST | LA MESA | 555-456-1234 |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 123 MAIN ST | LA MESA | 555-456-1235 |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 456 MAIN ST | LA MESA | 555-456-1234 |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 789 MAIN ST | SANTA CLARA | 555-456-1234 |

I am trying to put an indicator column labeled unique based on name, SSN, and county. Only 1 of the rows can have a Y for unique and any subsequent rows with that name, ssn, county combo would be N. Like this:

| NAME | SSN | ADDRESS | COUNTY | PHONE | UNIQUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 123 MAIN ST | LA MESA | 555-456-1234 | Y |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 123 MAIN ST | LA MESA | 555-456-1235 | N |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 456 MAIN ST | LA MESA | 555-456-1234 | N |
| MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 789 MAIN ST | SANTA CLARA | 555-456-1234 | Y |

Any ideas how I would go about doing this in Oracle(SQL)?

Comment: And how would you decide which row to make "unique"?  This sounds like a data normalization problem.  Create two tables - one of the name, ssn, county, and another for all the attributes that can change.

Comment: Perhaps unique isn't the right word, but that is the column they are asking for. We are creating a report for a client and they want a list of all columns above. But they also want to be able to filter by an indicator, in excel, and only have unique name, ssn, and county combo rows show up (with the other columns included).

Comment: You need to provide some criteria to select one specific row from a group of identical rows. Or explicitly state that this is not required and any arbitrary row may be marked as master record

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By NAME,SSN,COUNTY Order By ADDRESS,PHONE)` then check if the row number value is equal to one as the following:

```
Select NAME,SSN,ADDRESS,COUNTY,PHONE,
(Case When RN=1 Then 'Y' Else 'N' End) AS UNI
From
(
  Select NAME,SSN,ADDRESS,COUNTY,PHONE,
  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By NAME,SSN,COUNTY Order By ADDRESS,PHONE) RN
  From MyData
) D
```

Or

```
Select NAME,SSN,ADDRESS,COUNTY,PHONE,
(
  Case When ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By NAME,SSN,COUNTY Order By ADDRESS,PHONE)=1 
  Then 'Y' Else 'N' End
) AS UNI
From MyData
```

See a demo from ***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34046347553a940eceae794d70cdeb53)***.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer `lag/lead` to generate the first row indicator. These functions accept three arguments:

- an expression to get at the offset
- an offset in the number of rows to get an expression from
- a default value to provide as a result when the function goes beyond the partition boundary.

So the first argument should be the value to set for all the rows except the first one, the third argument should be the value to set for the first row (where `lag` would leave the partition boundary). This code is more compact as it doesn't involve `case` expressions around an analytic function (which is quite hard to read).

> ```
> with a(NAME, SSN, ADDRESS, COUNTY, PHONE) as (
> select 'MARY MOUSE', '456-78-9012', '123 MAIN ST', 'LA MESA', '555-456-1234' from dual union all
> select 'MARY MOUSE', '456-78-9012', '123 MAIN ST', 'LA MESA', '555-456-1235' from dual union all
> select 'MARY MOUSE', '456-78-9012', '456 MAIN ST', 'LA MESA', '555-456-1234' from dual union all
> select 'MARY MOUSE', '456-78-9012', '789 MAIN ST', 'SANTA CLARA', '555-456-1234' from dual
> )
> select
>   a.*,
>   lag('N', 1, 'Y')
>     over(partition by name, ssn, county order by null) as unique_
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME       | SSN         | ADDRESS     | COUNTY      | PHONE        | UNIQUE_
> :--------- | :---------- | :---------- | :---------- | :----------- | :------
> MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 123 MAIN ST | LA MESA     | 555-456-1234 | Y      
> MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 123 MAIN ST | LA MESA     | 555-456-1235 | N      
> MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 456 MAIN ST | LA MESA     | 555-456-1234 | N      
> MARY MOUSE | 456-78-9012 | 789 MAIN ST | SANTA CLARA | 555-456-1234 | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d05bba589cadc9a331f20de61998bc91)*